# How to retrieve the connection string c#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012

I am using Microsoft Visual Studio. 
I was able to establish connection to a database odbc without writing any code. I went to `TOOLS` ... Etc.

Now I want to retrieve those code lines that established this connection.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps:

To edit a connection string stored in application settings:

In Solution Explorer, double-click the My Project icon (Visual Basic) or Properties icon (Visual C# to open the Project Designer.
Select the Settings tab.
Locate the connection you want to edit and select the text in the Value box.
Edit the connection string in the Value box.

Reference:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171887(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to see them, you can go into debugger, set a break point after the connection you read, Ctrl+Shirt+Q for Quick Watch.  and look through the object in memory

Answer (score 1):

```
SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection("connection string")
```

Read `SqlConnection` class in MSDN.